# Why does this idea to solve a absorption markov chain not work?

Tags: math, graph, markov-chains

Edit: Seems like my method works.

I encountered a programming question that required me to calculate probability of reaching terminal states.

After a few painstaking hours trying to solve it traditionally, I googled and found that it is called an absorption markov chain. And there is a formula for it.

However, I am trying to figure out what is missing from my solution because it seems correct.

[image]

Pardon the crude drawing. Basically there are **4** nodes in this graph, the black lines show the original transitions and probability, while the coloured lines show the paths to termination.

The steps is something like this:

1. Trace all possible paths to a termination point, sum up the probability of every path to the termination node. That is the probability of reaching the node.
2. Ignore cyclical paths. Meaning that the **"1/3"** transition from **4** to **1** is essentially ignored.

Reason for (2): Because we can assume that going back will increase the probability of every possible path in such a way that they still maintain the same relative probability to each other! For example, if I were to go back to **1** from **4**, then the chances of going to **2**, **3** and **4** will each increase by **1/27** (1/3 * 1/3 * 1/3), making the relative probability still equal to each other!

I hope the above makes sense.

3. Calculate the probability of each node as "probability of each node" / "probability of terminating" because by eliminating cyclical graphs, the probability of reaching each node will not be 1 anymore.

So given the above algorithm, here are the values found:

Red path: 1/3 
Green path: 1/3 
Blue path: 1/3 * 2/3 = 2/9

Probability to reach **3**: 1/3 
Probability to reach **2**: 2/9 + 1/3 = 5/9 
Total probability to terminate: 1/3 + 5/9 = 8/9

Hence, final probability to reach **3**:
(1/3) / (8/9) = 3/8

Final probability to reach **2**:
(5/9) / (8/9) = 5/8

If you are unsure about step (2), we can try it again!

Assume that we went from **1** to **4** and back to **1** again, this has a probability of 1/9.

From here, we can follow each coloured paths again * 1/9 probability.

When combined with the probabilities calculated earlier, this gives us:

10/27 probability to reach **3**. 
50/81 probability to reach **2**. 
Total terminating probability of 80/81.

New probability of terminating at **3** is now (10/27) / (80/81) = 3/8 (SAME) 
New probability of terminating at **2** is now (50/81) / (80/81) = 5/8 (SAME)

<s>However, the actual probabilities are (2/5) and (3/5) for **3** and **2** respectively, using an algorithm I found online (there is a slim chance it is wrong though).</s> *Turns out I used the online solution wrongly*

I realised my answer is actually pretty close, and I am not sure why is it wrong?

Comment: Not related to your question, but could you please share the problem.

Comment: What are the starting conditions? Each of the 4  states with equal probability? Or only states 1 and 4? Or...?

Comment: @JohanC Only starting at state (1), sorry about that.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino look up the google Doomsday_Fuel foobar challenge. The example in the question is not one of the test cases, but my algorithm here fails the test cases so I am unsure why.

Comment: @JohanC sorry for the confusion, something seems off, thank you for reading but I think the question should be closed until i resolve something on my end.

Comment: By inspection (that is, by looking at it without writing anything out), I'd say your solution is correct, 3/8 and 5/8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can represent the transitions of the Markov chain with a matrix `M`. In Python notation, this would look like:

```py
M = [[  0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3],
     [  0,   1,   0,   0],
     [  0,   0,   1,   0],
     [1/3, 2/3,   0,   0]])
```

And the probabilities with a vector `S`, initially with 100% in state 1.

```py
S = [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Multiplying S by M gives the new probabilities:

```py
S*M = [0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3]
S*M**2 = [1/9, 5/9, 1/3, 0]
S*M**3 = [0, 16/27, 10/27, 1/27]
S*M**4 = [1/81, 50/81, 10/27, 0]
S*M**n = [3**(-n)*((-1)**n + 1)/2,
          3**(-n)*((-1)**n + 5*3**n - 6)/8,
          3**(-n)*(-(-1)**n + 3*3**n - 2)/8,
          3**(-n)*(1 - (-1)**n)/2]
```

In the limit with `n` going to infinity, for even `n`, this would give

```py
[0, 5/8, 3/8, 0]
```

Also starting with 1, 2, 3 and 4 with equal probability:

```py
S = [1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4]
S*M = [1/12, 1/2, 1/3, 1/12]
S*M**2 = [1/36, 7/12, 13/36, 1/36]
S*M**n = [3**(-n)/4, 5/8 - 3*3**(-n)/8, 3/8 - 3**(-n)/8, 3**(-n)/4]
```

leading to the same limit `[0, 5/8, 3/8, 0]`.

Starting with 1 and 4 with equal probability:

```py
S = [1/2, 0, 0, 1/2]
S*M = [1/6, 1/2, 1/6, 1/6]
S*M**2 = [1/18, 2/3, 2/9, 1/18]
S*M**n = [3**(-n)/2, 3/4 - 3*3**(-n)/4, 1/4 - 3**(-n)/4, 3**(-n)/2]
```

gives another limit for `n` going to infinity:

```py
[0, 3/4, 1/4, 0]
```

Comment: So it seems like my method works, thank you!