# Google foobar Doomsday Fuel failing test cases, absorbing markov chain question

Tags: java, depth-first-search, markov-chains

This is a question related to the google foobar doomsday fuel question. I know that there exists answers out there but I am just wondering why my solution fails some test cases

The question can be found here: https://github.com/ivanseed/google-foobar-help/blob/master/challenges/doomsday_fuel/doomsday_fuel.md

**Question**

```
The challenge specification
Making fuel for the LAMBCHOP's reactor core is a tricky process because of the exotic matter involved. 
It starts as raw ore, then during processing, begins randomly changing between forms, eventually reaching a stable form. 
There may be multiple stable forms that a sample could ultimately reach, not all of which are useful as fuel.

Commander Lambda has tasked you to help the scientists increase fuel creation efficiency by predicting the end state of a given ore sample.
You have carefully studied the different structures that the ore can take and which transitions it undergoes.
It appears that, while random, the probability of each structure transforming is fixed.
That is, each time the ore is in 1 state, it has the same probabilities of entering the next state (which might be the same state).
You have recorded the observed transitions in a matrix. The others in the lab have hypothesized more exotic forms that the ore can become, but you haven't seen all of them.

Write a function answer(m) that takes an array of array of nonnegative ints representing how many times that state has gone to the next state,
and return an array of ints for each terminal state giving the exact probabilities of each terminal state, represented as the numerator for each state,
then the denominator for all of them at the end and in simplest form.
The matrix is at most 10 by 10. It is guaranteed that no matter which state the ore is in, there is a path from that state to a terminal state.
That is, the processing will always eventually end in a stable state. The ore starts in state 0.
The denominator will fit within a signed 32-bit integer during the calculation, as long as the fraction is simplified regularly.

For example, consider the matrix m:

[
  [0,1,0,0,0,1],  # s0, the initial state, goes to s1 and s5 with equal probability
  [4,0,0,3,2,0],  # s1 can become s0, s3, or s4, but with different probabilities
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s2 is terminal, and unreachable (never observed in practice)
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s3 is terminal
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s4 is terminal
  [0,0,0,0,0,0],  # s5 is terminal
]
So, we can consider different paths to terminal states, such as:

s0 -> s1 -> s3
s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s1 -> s4
s0 -> s1 -> s0 -> s5
Tracing the probabilities of each, we find that:

s2 has probability 0
s3 has probability 3/14
s4 has probability 1/7
s5 has probability 9/14
So, putting that together, and making a common denominator,
gives an answer in the form of [s2.numerator, s3.numerator, s4.numerator, s5.numerator, denominator]
which is: [0, 3, 2, 9, 14].
```

So I came up with a solution, which is better explained here: [Why does this idea to solve a absorption markov chain not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966477/why-does-this-idea-to-solve-a-absorption-markov-chain-not-work)

The basic idea is this:

1. Trace all possible paths to a termination point, sum up the probability of every path to the termination node. That is the probability of reaching the node.
2. Ignore cyclical paths. Because cyclical paths will increase the probability by the same proportion, and is not required.
3. Calculate the probability of each node as "probability of each node" / "probability of terminating" because by eliminating cyclical paths, the probability of terminating will not be 1 anymore.

So this is the code I came up with, it is a DFS solution. I understand that its not the most elegant/pretty/"best practice" code, but it does the steps I listed.

**Solution.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Solution {
    
    // for dealing with fractions
    public static class Fraction {
        long denom;
        long numer;
        
        public Fraction(long numer, long denom) {
            // if representing zeroes, don't try to find GCD
            if (numer == 0) {
                this.numer = numer;
                this.denom = denom;
                return;
            }
            // simplify regularly
            long gcd = findGCD(numer, denom);
            this.numer = numer / gcd;
            this.denom = denom / gcd;
        }
        
        // raise to a denom without simplifying.
        // for example 1/2 -> 2/4
        // newDenom must be a multiple of current denom
        public void raiseToDenom(long newDenom) {
            if (newDenom % this.denom != 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Denom!");
            }
            this.numer = this.numer * (newDenom / this.denom);
        }
        
        public Fraction multiply(Fraction other) {
            return new Fraction(numer * other.numer, denom * other.denom);
        }
        
        public Fraction divide(Fraction other) {
            return new Fraction(numer * other.denom, denom * other.numer);
        }
        
        public Fraction add(Fraction other) {
            long lcm = findLCM(denom, other.denom);
            long newNumer = numer * (lcm / denom) + other.numer * (lcm / other.denom);
            return new Fraction(newNumer, lcm);
        }
        
        public static long findGCD(long first, long second) {
            if (second == 0) {
                return first;
            }
            return findGCD(second, first % second);
        }
        
        public static long findLCM(long first, long second) {
            return (first / findGCD(first,second)) * second;
        }
    }
    
    public static class Solver {
        private int states; // matrix.length
        private int[][] matrix;
        private int[] matrixToFractionArr; // map state num -> fraction arr
        private Fraction[] fractionArr; // each entry is for one terminal state
        
        public Solver(int[][] matrix) {
            this.matrix = matrix;
            this.states = matrix.length;
            this.matrixToFractionArr = new int[states];
            int terminalIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
                boolean isTerminal = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                    // if there is any entry that is not 0, this is not a terminal node...
                    // transitions to ownself is still considered terminal I think
                    if (matrix[i][j] != 0 && i != j) {
                        isTerminal = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // map to the fraction array
                if (isTerminal) {
                    matrixToFractionArr[i] = terminalIndex;
                    terminalIndex ++;
                } else {
                    matrixToFractionArr[i] = -1;
                }
            }
            // fractions for terminal states only
            this.fractionArr = new Fraction[terminalIndex];
            for (int i = 0; i < terminalIndex; i++) {
                // initial probabilty 0.
                this.fractionArr[i] = new Fraction(0,1);
            }
        }
        
        public int sumArray(int[] array) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                count += array[i];
            }
            return count;
        }
        
        // dfs method for setting the fractionArr correctly
        // carries the current probability by multiplying as we go, then adding it to terminal states
        // path represents which states is currently on path.
        public void setFractionsRecursively(Fraction currentProbability,
            int currentState, HashMap<Integer, Boolean> path) {
                
            int fractionIndex = matrixToFractionArr[currentState];
            if (fractionIndex != -1) {
                // it is a terminal node!
                // add the probability
                fractionArr[fractionIndex] = fractionArr[fractionIndex].add(currentProbability);
                return;
            }
            
            // not a terminal node, lets count the total outgoing
            int arrayTotal = sumArray(matrix[currentState]);
            // put this state on path
            path.put(currentState, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < states; i++) {
                int nextStateProb = matrix[currentState][i];
                if (nextStateProb == 0) {
                    // skip if cannot go this.
                    continue;
                }
                if (path.containsKey(i) && path.get(i)) {
                    // ensure that next state not on current path
                    // "i" is the next state to go to
                    continue;
                }
                Fraction nextProb = new Fraction(nextStateProb, arrayTotal);
                nextProb = nextProb.multiply(currentProbability);
                // dfs search
                setFractionsRecursively(nextProb, i, path);
            }
            // remove from path
            path.put(currentState, false);
            return;
        }
        
        // only can be used once unfortunately.
        public int[] solve() {
            // dfs related solution
            setFractionsRecursively(new Fraction(1,1), 0, new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>());
            // all fractions have been placed properly...
            
            // total "terminating probability"
            // essential because my method does not add up to one.
            Fraction total = new Fraction(0,1);
            for (int i = 0; i < fractionArr.length; i++) {
                total = total.add(fractionArr[i]);
            }
            
            // change probability to be over the "total" instead of one.
            for (int i = 0; i < fractionArr.length; i++) {
                fractionArr[i] = fractionArr[i].divide(total);
            }     
            
            // look for the LCM denominator to change all fractions to.
            long bestDenomLcm = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < fractionArr.length; i++) {
                bestDenomLcm = Fraction.findLCM(bestDenomLcm, fractionArr[i].denom);
            }
            
            long[] answerArray = new long[fractionArr.length + 1];
            // raise all fractions to LCM denom
            for (int i = 0; i < fractionArr.length; i++) {
                fractionArr[i].raiseToDenom(bestDenomLcm);
                answerArray[i] = fractionArr[i].numer;
            }
            
            // the total (last entry) is basically the denominator
            answerArray[answerArray.length - 1] = bestDenomLcm;
            
            // look for a GCD to
            // simplify it more if possible....
            // [2, 4, 6, 8] -> [1, 2, 3, 4] for example.
            long bestGcd = bestDenomLcm;
            for (int i = 0; i < answerArray.length; i++) {
                if (answerArray[i] != 0) {
                    bestGcd = Fraction.findGCD(bestGcd, answerArray[i]);
                }
            }
            
            // required because I used long...
            int[] intAnswerArray = new int[answerArray.length];
            
            // simplify here
            for (int i = 0; i < answerArray.length; i++) {
                intAnswerArray[i] = (int) (answerArray[i] /= bestGcd);
            }
            return intAnswerArray;
        }
    }
    
    // method that is called by test cases.
    public static int[] solution(int[][] m) {
        Solver solver = new Solver(m);
        int[] answer = solver.solve();
        return answer;
    }
}
```

**The answer will be derived by calling the Solution.solution(int[][] m) method.**

And I am failing **some** of the hidden test cases. I have passed the test case given in the question above.

So there are a few possibilities I have considered:

1. My algorithm doesn't work, and I hope someone can explain why...
2. There is a bug in my code, something I did not account for.
3. Runtime is too slow
4. Integer overflow when working with fractions (unlikely because I use long and the question specifies that it should not overflow).

Unfortunately the google foobar interface does not show the reasons, and I do not even know the test cases to try.

I have tried using random number generators, and sometimes there is integer overflows, however I still think the test cases provided should not be affected by overflow?

Thank you for reading this and I hope someone knows why. Hopefully it is not (3) and (4) because that will send you guys on a wild goose chase.

Comment: getting same issue: 1 and 2 pass, but most hidden test cases failed.
have you figured it out?